# What do sparse sets in a norm topology look like in the weak* topology?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology

I'm wondering if a very "sparse" set in a normed vector space can look connected in the weak* topology.  Specifically,

Let V be a Banach space, V* its dual, and X a (uncountable) subset of the unit ball in V* such that any two points in X are distance at least 1/2 apart from each other.  Now forget the norm on V* for a moment and endow it with the weak* topology instead.  Could X be connected?  Could it be weak*-dense in the unit ball?  Could it contain, say, the image of a closed interval under a non-constant, continuous (with respect to the weak* topology on V*, of course) map?

Interesting examples of what can or can't happen are welcome.  FWIW, the space that I was looking at that prompted this question comes from bounded cohomology of groups, but finding interesting examples in, say, $L^\infty[0,1]$ would be fine by me.

Comment: Take $V=C[0,1]$.  $[0,1]$ lives in $(V^*,w^*)$ as pointwise evaluations but is discrete in $(V^*,\|\cdot \|)$.

Answer (score 4):

(This post seems to have been deleted automatically, although a functional analyst has told me that the question seems reasonable. I am therefore undeleting and promoting Bill Johnson's comment to an answer. He is cordially invited to answer himself, whereupon this answer can be deleted.)

"Take $V=C[0,1]$.  $[0,1]$ lives in $(V^*,w^*)$ as pointwise evaluations but is discrete in $(V^*,\|\cdot \|)$."